# PHP Header redirect to Multiple URLs with a time gap

Tags: php, header

Can i use header() to redirect to multiple URLs with a time gap in between? Suppose i have url1 and url2. Now, what i want is that header first redirects to url1. Then say,after 5 seconds, it redirects me to url2. Is there a way i can do that?
I tried the following simple code

```
<?php
header("Location: url1");
header("Location: url2");
?>
```

But this takes me immediately to url2. I want a time gap in between. How can that be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any hint how to implement in JS?

Comment: you should accept the answer that have helped you most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by subirkumarsao, Martin and Edmunds, iframes is the way to go.
Here is the final code:

```
<html>
<iframe src="url1" width="500" height="500"> </iframe>
</html>

<?php
include('exp2.php');
?>
```

Now exp2.php has a submit button(This appears at the bottom of frame) which takes me to next.php. And next.php has the code:

```
<?php
header("Location:url2");
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not how it works.  The redirect will take you to a new page...and THAT page would then have to do the next redirect.  You should do something like:

PAGE 1:

```
<?php
header("Location: url1");
exit();
?>
```

PAGE 2:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=url2">
</head>
```

Comment: Not really.  I suppose you could do something particularly roundabout by launching a separate window, have that window trigger the redirects in the parent window and then close itself...but that is both poor form and rather complicated.  Why can't you edit the intermediary page?  If you really cannot, then maybe you should just push data to it or something.  Maybe you can provide more detail about what you are actually trying to do, as this whole scenario seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Both headers are immediately sent to the browser, with the latter one overwriting the first one. You can add "Refresh: X" before the url, but it will only work for the last header sent (the URL that will get redirected to).

Actually I don't see any way to accomplish this unless you control what is on url1 or use some tricks with frames.

Comment: thats correct. also i don't have any control over url1. is it possible to define a time gap between the two urls with frames?

Comment: Well what you could do is redirect to url0 that you control and create a page there that contains an iframe that is 100% width and 100% height and loads url1 inside. And then from the page at url0 do header("Location: url2").

Answer (score 0):

When you have been redirected to `url1` you no longer posses the control to do another redirection.

You need to specifically redirect from `url1` to `url2` on `url1`.

You can also try iframe if you dont have control over `url1`

Comment: will it be possible to define a time gap between the two urls with iframe?

Comment: You need to load an iframe and then through javascript change the url at an interval.

Answer (score 0):

In the header:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var time = null
function move() {
myiframe.location.href = 'url2';
}
</script>
```

and this in the body:

```
<body onload="timer=setTimeout('move()',2000)"> //where 2000 is 2 seconds
<iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" src="url1"> </iframe>
```

Cheers

Comment: i don't have any control over url1. any other way?